# Probability of solving all 7 questions

Tags: probability

A student studies 15 problems.He can solve 9 of them. The instructor selects 7 questions out of the 15. What is the probability that the student can solve all 7 problems?

P.s If you know what type of questions these are, please tell me so I can study them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total number of ways to choose $7$ out of $15$ problems is $\binom{15}{7}=6435$

The number of ways to choose $7$ out of $9$ **solvable** problems is $\binom{9}{7}=36$

Hence the probability of choosing only solvable problems is $\frac{36}{6435}\approx0.5\%$

Answer (score 0):

These are probability problems involving concepts from combinatorics, which involve permutations and combinations. You might want to these formulae, after getting a good understanding of how exactly they can be used.

You can refer to this: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

The above link will suffice in teaching you the required concepts and formulae for this question (Essentially, will help you evaluate the right sample space as well as fav. events for this question). If you have any doubts even after having a thorough read of what's in the link, leave a comment so that I can clarify further.

More problems here: http://questions.ascenteducation.com/iim_cat_mba_free_sample_questions_math_quant/permutation_combination/

Comment: Your answer should really be a comment.